# How get order items using entity_id

Tags: magento2, order-items

This File responsible for setting Grand Total in Order Grid. I test it.

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Magento\Sales\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;
use Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface;

/**
 * Class Price
 */
class Price extends Column
{
    /**
     * @var PriceCurrencyInterface
     */
    protected $priceFormatter;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param ContextInterface $context
     * @param UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory
     * @param PriceCurrencyInterface $priceFormatter
     * @param array $components
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        PriceCurrencyInterface $priceFormatter,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->priceFormatter = $priceFormatter;
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Prepare Data Source
     *
     * @param array $dataSource
     * @return array
     */
    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
                $currencyCode = isset($item['base_currency_code']) ? $item['base_currency_code'] : null;
                $item[$this->getData('name')] = $this->priceFormatter->format(
                    $item[$this->getData('name')],
                    false,
                    null,
                    null,
                    $currencyCode
                );
            }
        }

        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

**$item** array return all orders i print one order `print_r($item)` `die('');`

> Array ( [id_field_name] => entity_id [entity_id] => 53 [status] => pending [store_id] => Main Website
>          Main Website Store
>             Default Store View
>       [store_name] => Main Website Main Website Store [customer_id] => 1 [base_grand_total] => 2623.9800 [base_total_paid] => [grand_total] => 2623.9800 [total_paid] => [increment_id] => 000000130 [base_currency_code] => USD [order_currency_code] => USD [shipping_name] => Veronica Costello [billing_name] => Veronica Costello [created_at] => 2019-02-25 19:46:38 [updated_at] => 2019-02-25 14:46:38 [billing_address] => 6146 Honey Bluff Parkway Calder Michigan 49628-7978 [shipping_address] => 6146 Honey Bluff Parkway Calder Michigan 49628-7978 [shipping_information] => Best Way - Table Rate [customer_email] => roni_cost@example.com [customer_group] => 1 [subtotal] => 3030.0000 [shipping_and_handling] => 0.0000 [customer_name] => Veronica Costello [payment_method] => checkmo [total_refunded] =>

I want to get order Items from **sales_order_item** table when I give a specific id like => `$item['entity_id']` then it return all the **order items** of specific id `$item['entity_id']`.

How can do this? kindly guide me little bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

Add the below code in your controller

```
<?php                                                         
namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Controller\Orders;                    
class ReadOrders extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action         
{
  protected $resultPageFactory;
  protected $itemFactory;
  public function __construct(
    \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\ItemFactory $itemFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
  ) {
    $this->itemFactory = $itemFactory;
    $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    parent::__construct($context);
 }
 public function execute()
 {
    $entity_id = 1; // give your entity_id here to get the details of items
    $order = $this->itemFactory->create()->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('order_id', $entity_id);
    foreach ($order as $items) {
        echo 'Order Id :'.$itemId =  $items->getItemId() . '<br>';
        echo 'Status :'.$items->getStatus(). '<br>';
        echo 'Product Name :'.$items->getName(). '<br>';
    }
 }}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: let me check it.

Comment: Dear how can get on same class ?
I try this \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepo in constructor and try to get . it generate error 
`Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 383778816) (tried to allocate 360714240 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\market-place\vendor\magento\module-sales\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Price.php on line 56`

Comment: Updated now hitting the item table passing the order_id also known as the entity id from sales_order table. and It works fine, try it and let me know

Comment: Yes it work Thanks. here 1 condition check `$order = $this->itemFactory->create()->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('order_id', $entity_id);`  i need 2 condition. 
in sales_order_item table i have a custom attribute "seller_id" i want to check 2 condition like entity_id and seller_id.
How use addFieldToFilter on 2 condidtions ?

Comment: $this->itemFactory->create()->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('order_id', $entity_id)->addFieldToFilter('seller_id',$seller_id);

this filters out those matching :)